# Add to blocks from the DocPad configuration file

Tags: docpad

How to add to blocks from the configuration file?

Eg: Set a list of scripts/styles to include in the block by doing something like:

```
    @getBlock('scripts').add([
        '/vendor/jquery.js'
        '/vendor/jquery-ui.js'
    ])
```

In the configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Issue #387](https://github.com/bevry/docpad/issues/387) on GitHub, [answered by balupton](https://github.com/bevry/docpad/issues/387#issuecomment-11799691):

There are two ways we generally can do this.

## Via TemplateData

```
templateData:
    site:
        scripts: [
            '/vendor/jquery.js'
            '/vendor/jquery-ui.js'
            ]
```

Then inside your layout:

```
<%- @getBlock('scripts').add(@site.scripts).toHTML()
```

## Via Populate Collections Event

```
events:
    populateCollections: ->
        @getBlock('scripts').add([
            '/vendor/jquery.js'
            '/vendor/jquery-ui.js'
        ])
```

Comment: actually, there is a slight correction:

in populateCollections(), the @getBlock does not work (atleast not anymore...), you have to do @.docpad.blocks['scripts']